# Powershell csv when empty cell - delete row

Tags: csv, row, cell

I have a csv file which has 8 columns. When columns 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 are blank, the whole row need to be deleted.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont
cont,cont,cont,cont,,cont,cont,cont     --> delete row
cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,,cont     --> delete row
cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont,cont
```

How can I solve this with Powershell?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to do something like this:

```
foreach ($line in Get-Content .\myfile.txt) {
   $linearray = $line.split(",");
   if($linearray[4] && $linearray[5] && $linearray[6] & $linearray[7]) {
      Add-Content .\myTempfile.txt $line
   }
}
Out-File .\myfile.txt .\myTempFile.txt
Remove-Item .\myTempFile.txt
```